# 404 Not Found (Source not found on the server) Slim Framework

Tags: php, url, slim, url-parameters

I am willing to get a json response whether an administrator is registered or not. So I made this get function with these parameters shown below:

```
$app->get('/admin/:email/:password', function($email, $password){

    $password = md5($password);

    $databaseObject = new DatabaseLayer();
    $isRegistered = $databaseObject->isAdminExist($email, $password);

    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    if ($isRegistered){
        $app->response->setStatus('200');   
        $app->response->headers->set('Content_Type', 'application/json');   
        echo json_encode(Array('isLogin' => '1'));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(Array('isLogin' => '0'));
    }
});
```

My problem is when I add a point to the email parameter, it doesn't work.
Here is a screenshot with no point in the email param:

[image: Screenshot of the working url]

Here is a second screenshot with a point in the email param:

[image: Screenshot of the not working url]

Please can I get some help, this is for a project I am making.
Thank you.

**For more further information, I am using Slim version 2.***

Comment: Using an `@` in a url path could cause some issues with routing. BTW it's not a good place to pass sensitive data (like email and a plain password) in a url.

Answer (score 0):

Your route should be like this:

```
$app->get('/admin/{email}/{password}', function($email, $password){
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :(
Not even with two simple parameters